# Updating contenteditable DIV with spaces

Tags: javascript, css

I have a web page that has a DIV on it. This DIV is marked as `contenteditable`. I need the DIV to be "inline". I also need it to be a minimum size. Since inline elements can't have a min-width, I'm trying to fake it by using a string of `&nbsp;`.

Basically, as a user types, I want to add or remove &nbsp elements unless the string is longer than the minimum size. My problem is, when rendered, it seems that every-other   element is rendered as a space. This throws my math off. I'm not sure why this is happening. I've created a Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nh1k12bg/). The JavaScript for this looks like this:

```
function onKeyDown(elem, spaceCount) {
  var space = '&nbsp;';
  var spacesToAdd = '';
  var addSpaceCount = 0;

  var d = document.getElementById('debug');


  var spaceIndex = elem.innerHTML.indexOf(space);
  if (spaceIndex !== -1) {
    addSpaceCount = (elem.innerHTML.length - spaceIndex) / (space.length);
    d.value += 'text: ' + elem.innerHTML + '\n';
    d.value += 'len: ' + elem.innerHTML.length + ' index: ' + spaceIndex + ' count: ' + addSpaceCount + ' original: ' + spaceCount + '\n\n';      

    for (var i=0; addSpaceCount > i; i++) {
      spacesToAdd += '&nbsp;';
    }
  }

  var updated = elem.innerHTML.substring(0, spaceIndex) + spacesToAdd;
  elem.innerHTML = updated;
}
```

How do I ensure that the string within my DIV is always a minimum length? If its less than the minimum length, I just want to add some spaces to get to the minimum length so that my DIV renders as I want.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you wnat a minimum space? Just so you can see it?

Answer (score 8):

Use `white-space: pre-wrap;` in CSS property for contenteditable.

Comment: Great hint. I use a `div` switchable between `contenteditable` and not and it sent &nbsp; instead of space characters to the server. With `white-space: pre` editing inserts plain 0x20 into the text. And yes, leading and trailing space is then intentionally removed by the tour through the server, so not seeing them in the `div` when `contenteditable` is off is just right.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just have the inline thing show, give it a style of `display:inline-block;` and a `min-width:100px;` (or whatever).  then it will always show as a minimum area.

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="border-bottom:solid 1px blue; display:inline-block; min-width:100px; outline:none;" onkeydown="onKeyDown(this, 5);">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nh1k12bg/1/

Update 
Try using a simple `display:block; float:left;` instead on your element.

https://jsfiddle.net/nh1k12bg/2/

Comment: I cant use inline-block. The reason why is because if you add text that extends past the end of the current line, the current line gets pushed down to the next line. That's why I'm using spaces.

Comment: @user70192, have you tried using a simple display:block; float:left?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`display:inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) then you don't need the JS.

> The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with
>   surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much
>   like a replaced element would)

```css
span {display:inline-block; min-width:200px; border-bottom:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<p>Who said <span>inline elements</span> can't have a minimum width?</p>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nh1k12bg/2/)

### Update. Can't use inline block?

You could use a css `:after` pseudo filled with spaces and have your JS edit that content so that its doesn't mess with the actual text being inputted.

```js
var editables = document.querySelectorAll("div[contenteditable=true]");
for(e=0; e<editables.length; e++){
  editables[e].addEventListener("input",onInput);
  onInput.call(editables[e]);
}
function onInput() {
  var elem = this,
      minLen = elem.getAttribute("data-minlen"),
      space = '\u00A0',//a hex nbsp
      spacesToAdd = '',
      addSpaceCount = minLen - elem.innerHTML.length;
  //add spaces
  for(i=0; i<addSpaceCount; i++){spacesToAdd += space;}
  elem.setAttribute("data-mincontent",spacesToAdd);
}
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {border-bottom:solid 1px blue; display:inline; outline:none;}
div[contenteditable]:after {content: attr(data-mincontent);}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum <div contenteditable="true" data-minlen="5"></div> dolor sit amet, <div contenteditable="true" data-minlen="20"></div> consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

As you can see I've used an event listener rather than inline events and have set it up so you can have any number of content editable regions on the page. All you have to do is set the `minLen` data attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/nh1k12bg/4/

Comment: I cant use inline-block. The reason why is because if you add text that extends past the end of the current line, the current line gets pushed down to the next line. That's why I'm using spaces.

Comment: @user70192 I've updated my answer to include a JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my bugs using

```
<div (blur)="changeText($event.target.innerHTML)"> </div>
```

Blur fixes cursor position bugs and my function replace   for white space.

```
   public changeText(event, el): void {
    var re = /&nbsp;/gi;
    var str = event;
    var newstr = str.replace(re, ' ');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pre element. It respects whatever space inside the element ##

```html
<div contentEditable="true" >
  <pre ></pre>
</div>
```